Sending long-term DH public keys via a one-time-use DH key pair
I am developing a hobby project - a secure chatroom system, where I've developed a BigNum arithmetic library and a cryptography library in C from scratch, and coming up with a theoretical scheme that would make the chatroom cryptographically secure and authenticated.
I've already implemented ChaCha20, Blake2b, (a close enough version of) Argon2id, Schnorr Signature generator and verifier, generators of public and private keys, Montgomery Modular Multiplication and others, and I've found my own 3071-bit diffie-hellman prime modulus M, generator G and 320-bit prime Q that exactly divides (M-1).
I have one specific question related to how users (client machines) can send their long-term public key to the server machine at the start of each session, in a secure and authenticated manner, avoiding sending the public key in the clear.
The construction for the initial handshake between a client connecting to the server to start chatting with others, to avoid sending the client's long-term public key to the server unencrypted and unauthenticated, is the following:

Client wants to contact the server to login / register. Client already has the server's long-term public key embedded with installation.

Client generates a short-term one time use DH private/public key pair (a_s, A_s):
a_s = random from /dev/urandom in range (1, Q] (one-time-use private key)
A_s = G^a_s mod M  (one-time-use public key)

Client connects to the server, sending their one-time-use public key A_s in the clear.

Server makes sure that (0 < A_s < M) and that A_s^(M/Q) mod M = 1.

If checks are OK, server generates its own one-time-use DH private/public key pair (b_s,B_s).

Server computes X  = A_s^b_s mod M

Server extracts two keys KAB and KBA and a value Y from first, second and third 32-byte regions of X.

Server computes a Schnorr Signature of Y using its long-term private key b, yielding SB. (verifying a signature of an unused part of X is needed for the security of this to work I believe).

Server sends the initial reply to the client containing the signature of Y and its one-time-use public key: (SB,B_s), protected by an authenticated cipher (HMAC) and key KBA:


This means, starting with plainly concatenated (SB,B_s) as a single stream of bytes, server first encrypts them with ChaCha20, using key KBA and Nonce from an unused region of X (that the client's software is precomputed to know about). This yields N1 = chacha20( (SB,B_s), KBA, Nonce).
Then, the server feeds the encrypted version of (SB,B_s) to HMAC for authentication, using unkeyed Blake2B as HMAC's encryptor and the same key as chacha20 for the Key (KBA). Server trims the result of HMAC to 8 bytes, appends these 8 bytes to N1 (the encrypted (SB,B_s)). Let's call the 8 bytes that HMAC gave us from the encrypted (SB,B_s) N2.

The server's initial reply to the client is concatenated (N1, N2).
Client receives the server's initial reply.
Client must compute the same HMAC that the server computed, in order to authenticate the server's reply. For that, the client must compute the same X that the server computed in order to extract the key KBA. This is where I'm confused.

MY QUESTION IS how is the client supposed to compute the same HMAC result as the server, using key KBA extracted from X, if it needs the encrypted server's one-time-use public key B_s in order to compute X and extract the key KBA to decrypt the server's one-time-use public key in the first place?
Does the server simply not encrypt its one-time-use public key B_s, instead sending it to the client in the clear, just like the client sent its own short-term one-time-use public key A_s in the clear at the beginning? And then the only thing that the server encrypts with chacha20 in its initial reply is SB (the schnorr signature of Y, the unused part of X)? This is the only way I can see that the client is able to compute the same short-term (X = B_s_^a_s mod M) in order to extract key KBA, proceed to authenticate the server's reply by computing the same HMAC and comparing the trimmed 8 bytes of it with the trimmed 8 bytes the server sent, then using the already embedded at install-time server's long-term public key to verify the schnorr signature, then proceed to use the other key KAB extracted from X at both sides to send its own reply to the server, this time containing the client's long-term public key in encrypted and authenticated form again with chacha20 and HMAC, destroying the one-time-use DH key pair after that, to begin using the long-term DH key pair?
Or am I missing something in this hand-shake to avoid sending the client's long-term public key unprotected before the two sides are able to begin communicating over the secure and authenticated channel provided by the long-term DH key pairs and schnorr signatures?

This is why we have Trusted Certificate Authorities. Why don't you store each client public key before hand?

@kelalaka The chatroom server can't know who will be using it. A client generates its own new long-term DH key pair when it installs the chat system and the server's long-term public key is already there in the client as well from installation. What I'm wondering is, is it safe for the server to transmit its one-time-use public key in the clear and unprotected, given that it will be destroyed as soon as the client uses it to transmit its long-term public key to the server? New session-length keys KBA, KAB are generated each time, that's why the client sends its long-term public key each time.
